# Entity Framework 5 Won't Fetch Relationships With Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am quite certain that questions like this have been answered a number of times before, but I can't get any of the suggestions to work.

I am building a MVC 4 application with Entity Framework 5, where the entities were generated from existing tables.  I have entity classes that look like this:

```
namespace RebuildingModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class StandardCodeTable
    {
        public StandardCodeTable()
        {
            this.StandardCodeTableTexts = new HashSet<StandardCodeTableText>();
        }

        public int TableCode { get; set; }
        public string RefTableName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StandardCodeTableText> StandardCodeTableTexts { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace RebuildingModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class StandardCodeTableText
    {
        public int TableCode { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string TextVal { get; set; }

        public virtual StandardCodeTable StandardCodeTable { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace RebuildingSite.Models
{
    public class CodeTableJoined
    {
        public int TableCode { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceTableName { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string TextValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a DAO that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RebuildingModel.Dao
{
    public class CodeTableDao
    {
        public CodeTableDao() { }

        public ISet<StandardCodeTableText> GetCode(string refTableName)
        {
            HashSet<StandardCodeTableText> codes = new HashSet<StandardCodeTableText>();

            using (var db = new RebuildingTogetherEntities())
            {
                db.StandardCodeTableTexts.Include("StandardCodeTables");

                var query = from c in db.StandardCodeTableTexts
                            where c.StandardCodeTable.RefTableName == refTableName
                            orderby c.TableCode
                            select c;

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    codes.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return codes;
        }
}
```

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
namespace RebuildingSite.Controllers
{
    public class CodeTableController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string refTableName)
        {
            CodeTableDao dao = new CodeTableDao();

            ICollection<StandardCodeTableText> codes = dao.GetCode(refTableName);

            HashSet<CodeTableJoined> joins = new HashSet<CodeTableJoined>();

            foreach (var code in codes)
            {
                CodeTableJoined join = new CodeTableJoined();

                join.TableCode = code.TableCode;
                join.LanguageCode = code.LanguageCode;
                join.TextValue = code.TextVal;
                join.ReferenceTableName = code.StandardCodeTable.RefTableName;

                joins.Add(join);
            }

            ISet<string> refTableNames = dao.GetReferenceTables();

            ViewBag.RefTableNames = refTableNames;

            return View(joins);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the view attached to the controller, an ObjectDisposedException is thrown at this line, where the relationship is used:

```
join.ReferenceTableName = code.StandardCodeTable.RefTableName;
```

This has to be something simple.  What am I doing wrong?  I have tried adding that Include() call in from the context in many different places, even multiple times.
I've also tried adding an explicit join in the Linq query.  I can't get EF to fetch that relationship.

Comment: SHould the include be in the actual query?
  ` var query = from c in db.StandardCodeTableTexts.include("StandardCodeTables").
                            where c.StandardCodeTable.RefTableName == refTableName
                            orderby c.TableCode
                            select c;`

Comment: Of course!  I knew it was something simple.  That was dumb of me - thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my comment to an answer - Put the include be in the actual query

```
 var query = from c in
 db.StandardCodeTableTexts.include("StandardCodeTables"). where
 c.StandardCodeTable.RefTableName == refTableName orderby c.TableCode
 select c;
```